# How to stop personalizing my page?

Tags: 2010, personalization

How do I take my page out of personalization mode after doing the following?

1. Select "Personalize this Page"
2. Click "Add a Web Part"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you mean to confirm your changes, click "Page" on the ribbon, then click "Stop Editing" on the left.

If you mean you want to switch back to the shared view of the page, click "Stop Editing" as above, click your username on the top right and click "Show Shared View".

Comment: Surely this is the correct answer, and I'll likely mark it as such soon, but I've asked a related question in the meantime (I don't see the "Stop Editing" you mention): http://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/30362/why-can-i-not-stop-personalizing