# Why can I not stop personalizing?

Tags: 2010, ribbon, personalization

When I "Personalize this Page", I don't seem to have a way to "Stop Editing". I'd expect such a button under the "Page" of the ribbon, but it's not there.

[image]

What can cause this?

Comment: It is possible your account doesn't have design permissions on the current page, which is causing the edit/stop editing buttons to be grayed out.  What options do you have under the username drop down on the top right, outside of this screenshot?

Comment: My Site, My Profile, My Settings, Sign in as Different User, Request Access, Sign Out, Personalize this Page, Reset Page Content

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't think it has anything to do with permissions - but of course check this first.

I think the publishing feature does not allow this on these types of pages.

For example - I created a simple list and tried to personalize the page - and it worked - it had the stop editing option.

But when I try and use a pages library with a blank web part page - I do not get the ribbon or option to stop editing.

Why? I don't know.

Simon King